# Generate an auto serial number and save the result in database

Tags: php

Could someone please help me out.

I got a code online on how to generate an auto serial number and edited it to fit my needs which ofcourse gives me my desired output. But in saving the results in the database, it saves only the last value which is "**99**" instead of all the values beginning from 00001.

I am cut in the middle on how to rewrite the code to save all the values in the database. Please someone look at the code below and advice

```
<?php require_once('Connections/@@@@@.php'); ?>

<?php
for($i = 1; $i < 100; $i++){
$result = str_pad($i, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '<br />';
echo $result;
} 
mysql_select_db($database_@@@@@, $@@@@@);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO codes (sn) VALUES ('$result')");
?>
```

Thank you

Comment: You're only running one insert query, that happens after you've generated all of the possible codes. You need to move the mysql_query() call inside your for loop, and ensure that mysql_select_db() happens before you enter that loop.

Comment: 100 times better to concatenate the results and run 1 query than to run 100 queries

Comment: @Dagon: I dont understand what you mean. Can you explain more

Comment: @shaunc: Your comment worked. I moved the mysql_select_db() inbetween the loop and the $result and it worked. But now I am haven the '<br />' also in the database like this "00094<br />". That is how the entries are. The you now why? It should be only "00094"

Comment: well your adding `<br>` to the string you add to the db, so of course they are there - see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For auto serial number, this is what I have been using

```
SELECT j.*, DATE_FORMAT( ddate,  '%d %M %Y' ) AS ddate2, DATE_FORMAT( dateapplied,  '%d %M %Y' ) AS dateapplied2, @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS sn
FROM jobsappltn j JOIN  (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
ORDER BY j.jaid DESC
```

With this you don't need to use the values of mysql auto increment id... Just place the values of the **sn** column as first column.

Your table will look like this

```
sn       Ddate2        Dateapplied2
1        09-09-2018    09-08-2018
2        10-09-2018    29-08-2018
```

Answer (score 0):

it is far better not to make 100 queries when 1 will do

```
<?php require_once('Connections/@@@@@.php'); ?>

<?php
$result ='';
for($i = 1; $i < 100; $i++){
$result .= "'".str_pad($i, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)."'," ;//crate concatenated string
// echo $result."<br>";
} 
$result = substr($result,0, -1); //removes last comma

mysql_select_db($database_@@@@@, $@@@@@);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO codes (sn) VALUES ($result)");
?>
```

this will insert all 100 in a single query, the `<br>` has also been removed from the db strings